# In R Shiny, how to reactively link a series of expandable user input matrices?

Tags: r, shiny, observers, shiny-reactivity

In the below shortened code, user inputs are "linked" in a series of 3 user input matrices (also illustrated in the images below):

1. Matrix 1: if user wants to run a rough and quick scenario, user would input into matrix 1 only. One variable, one scenario only.
2. Matrix 2: if user wants to run a more complex scenario, user would optionally input into matrix 2 with the matrix 1 input "downstreaming" to row 1 / column 2 of matrix 2 in order to seed it. Matrix 2 expands vertically to accommodate additional user inputs for generating a curve.
3. Matrix 3: if user wants to run multiple complex scenarios, user would optionally input into matrix 3, with scenario 1 of matrix 3 a downstream mirror reflection of matrix 2. Matrix 3 expands vertically and horizontally, to accommodate user inputs + additional scenarios.

Note that the more complete App runs inter/extrapolation calculations for generating curves. For the sake of simplicity, the below code runs a simple (and nonsensical) sumProduct instead. But the calculation is not the point of this post.

I've used `observeEvent` to successfully downstream the following user inputs:

- `observeEvent(input$matrix1...` downstreams user input from matrix 1 to matrix 2, and
- `observeEvent(input$matrix2...` downstreams user input from matrix 2 to scenario 1 of matrix 3 while preserving all inputs into scenarios > 1 in matrix 3.

What I have been unable to do is have user inputs into matrix 1 NOT erase those user inputs into matrix 3 scenarios > 1, as shown in the last image at the bottom. I've tried all sorts of `observeEvents` with no luck. Should I be using an `observe` instead? Where matrix 3 simply observes what's happening to matrix 2? Any ideas on how to do this?

I've been able to preserve matrix 3 scenario > 1 inputs when matrix 2 is changed with the code shown under `observeEvent(input$matrix2...`, but when I trying including this sort of code under `observeEvent(input$matrix1...` it doesn't work.

Here´s that code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

sumProd <- function(a, b) {
  c    <- rep(NA, a)
  c[]  <- sum(b[,1], na.rm = T) %*% sum(b[,2],na.rm = T) 
  return(c)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput('periods', 'Modeled periods (X):', min=1, max=10, value=10),
  matrixInput("matrix1", 
              value = matrix(c(5), nrow = 1, ncol = 1, dimnames = list("Base rate (Y)",NULL)),
              cols =  list(names = FALSE),
              class = "numeric"),
  matrixInput("matrix2",
              value = matrix(c(10,5), nrow = 1, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
              class = "numeric"),
  matrixInput("matrix3",
              value = matrix(c(10,5), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 2, delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
              class = "numeric"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  observeEvent(input$matrix1, {
    tmpMat2 <- c(input$matrix2[,1],input$matrix2[,2])
    tmpMat2[length(input$matrix2)/2+1] <- input$matrix1[,1]
    updateMatrixInput(session,inputId="matrix2",value=matrix(tmpMat2,ncol=2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("X","Y")))
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, { 
    a <- apply(input$matrix3,2,'length<-',max(nrow(input$matrix3),nrow(input$matrix2)))
    b <- apply(input$matrix2,2,'length<-',max(nrow(input$matrix3),nrow(input$matrix2)))
    c <- if(length(a) == 2){c(b)} else {c(b,a[,-1:-2])}
    d <- ncol(input$matrix3)
    tmpMat3 <- matrix(c(c), ncol = d)
    colnames(tmpMat3) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMat3),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMat3)))
    
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMat3 <- input$matrix2
      rownames(tmpMat3) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat3))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = tmpMat3))
    }
    input$matrix2
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = tmpMat3
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix3, {
    if(any(colnames(input$matrix3) == "")){
      tmpMat3 <- input$matrix3
      colnames(tmpMat3) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMat3),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMat3)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = tmpMat3))
    }
    input$matrix3
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix3)/2), # column counter to set matrix index as it expands
             function(i){
               tibble(
                 Scenario = colnames(input$matrix3)[i*2-1],
                 X = seq_len(input$periods),
                 Y = sumProd(input$periods,input$matrix3[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + 
      geom_line(aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = as.factor(Scenario))) +
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here are images showing what works and what doesn't:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a simple `observe` will not resolve the issue. Keep using `observeEvent`. There is an error in the originally posted code, in the `server` section under  `observeEvent(input$matrix2, {...` starting `if(any(rownames(input$matrix2) == "")){...` where both matrix 2 AND matrix 3 are updated. Matrix 3 should not be updated in this section under the `observeEvent` for matrix 2 input, where a row label is added for matrix 2. In the below resolved code, see how the `rownames` function is moved to the separate `observeEvent` for any input changes to matrix 3. With this fix the code now works.

Resolved code:

```
sumProd <- function(a, b) {
  c    <- rep(NA, a)
  c[]  <- sum(b[,1], na.rm = T) %*% sum(b[,2],na.rm = T) 
  return(c)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput('periods', 'Modeled periods (X):', min=1, max=10, value=10),
  matrixInput("matrix1", 
              value = matrix(c(5), nrow = 1, ncol = 1, dimnames = list("Base rate (Y)",NULL)),
              cols =  list(names = FALSE),
              class = "numeric"),
  matrixInput("matrix2",
              value = matrix(c(10,5), nrow = 1, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
              class = "numeric"),
  matrixInput("matrix3",
              value = matrix(c(10,5), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 2, delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
              class = "numeric"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix1, {
    tmpMat2 <- c(input$matrix2[,1],input$matrix2[,2]) # convert to vector
    tmpMat2[length(input$matrix2)/2+1] <- input$matrix1[,1] # drop matrix 1 value into row 1/col 2 of matrix 2
    updateMatrixInput(session,inputId="matrix2",value=matrix(tmpMat2,ncol=2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("X","Y"))))
    })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, {
    a <- apply(input$matrix3,2,'length<-',max(nrow(input$matrix3),nrow(input$matrix2)))
    b <- apply(input$matrix2,2,'length<-',max(nrow(input$matrix3),nrow(input$matrix2)))
    c <- if(length(a) == 2){c(b)} else {c(b,a[,-1:-2])}
    d <- ncol(input$matrix3)
    tmpMat3 <- matrix(c(c), ncol = d)
    colnames(tmpMat3) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMat3),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMat3)))

    if(any(rownames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMat2 <- input$matrix2
      rownames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2)
      }
    
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = tmpMat3)
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix3, {
    if(any(colnames(input$matrix3) == "")){
      tmpMat3 <- input$matrix3
      colnames(tmpMat3) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMat3),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMat3)))
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = tmpMat3)
      }
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix3) == "")){
      tmpMat3 <- input$matrix3
      rownames(tmpMat3) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix3)))
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = tmpMat3)
      }
    input$matrix3
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix3)/2), # column counter to set matrix index as it expands
             function(i){
               tibble(
                 Scenario = colnames(input$matrix3)[i*2-1],
                 X = seq_len(input$periods),
                 Y = sumProd(input$periods,input$matrix3[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + 
      geom_line(aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = as.factor(Scenario))) +
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```